# Py2neo: Generating Grid of Nodes and Relationship

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I am using Py2neo to generate a grid of nodes and relationship (2D Graph) aka Cellular Automata in Neo4j. My following code works but it only creates nodes but no relationship between them. Would like to know where I am doing wrong or if it's not possible to create nodes and relationship as Grid in Neo4j using Cypher or Python.

```html
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
def grid(x,y):   
    nodes=list(range(0,x*y))
    for node in nodes:
        graph.create(Node("Cell"))
        if Node(node%x!=0): #if we're not at the start of a line, then we connect to the node before
            graph.create(Relationship(Node(node), "Neighbors", Node(node-1)))
        if Node(node%x!=x-1): #if we're not at the end of a line, then we connect to the node after
            graph.create(Relationship(Node(node), "Neighbors", Node(node+1)))
        if Node(node>=x): #if we're not in the top row, then we connect to the node above
            graph.create(Relationship(Node(node), "Neighbors", Node(node-x)))
        if Node(node<x*(y-1)): #if we're not in the bottom row, then we connect to the node under
            graph.create(Relationship(Node(node), "Neighbors", Node(node+x)))
grid(3,3)
```

Comment: does `if Node(...)`create a node in the `if` expression ?

Comment: It doesn't. I used it for creating relationship. It's not right as no relationship is getting created.

Comment: i don’t get it .. you’re calling a constructor in the `if` expression so that expression will always be true.. therefore all the `if` cases will execute each iteration of the `for`... anyway i’m not sure what the syntax is for establishing relationships is but you’re also only ever calling `relationship` on one node at a time?